# In GM tubes, why are halogen quench gases not used with helium?

Tags: radiation, particle-detectors

In the [Wikipedia article on GM tubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger%E2%80%93M%C3%BCller_tube) it says "Halogens are most commonly used with neon, argon or krypton, organic quenchers with helium."

I thought helium would be a perfectly fine fill gas because its light weight should reduce the deadtime. But when it comes to routine applications like industrial safety, a consumable quench gas isn't very useful. What makes helium different from the heavier noble gasses in that respect?

Answer (score 2):

Mostly because helium will leak. Also because helium is expensive.